# Crash on memory warning

Tags: iphone, crash-reports

Can anyone help in analysing this crash issue?

```
    The program did receive memory warning when webview was opened.
    2011-05-10 10:52:44.882 [17713:207] *** -[CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xd0ee720
    (gdb) where
    #0  0x017d7057 in ___forwarding___ ()
    #1  0x017d6f22 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
    #2  0x017780bc in CFRetain ()
    #3  0x0185edb5 in +[__NSArrayI __new::] ()
    #4  0x013328f6 in -[CALayerArray copyWithZone:] ()
    #5  0x017c67ca in -[NSObject(NSObject) copy] ()
    #6  0x007378d7 in -[UIView dealloc] ()
    #7  0x007ac52a in -[UIViewController setView:] ()
    #8  0x007aeeec in -[UIViewController unloadViewForced:] ()
    #9  0x007aab0a in -[UIViewController unloadViewIfReloadable] ()
    #10 0x007b6194 in -[UINavigationController purgeMemoryForReason:] ()
    #11 0x007aa15b in -[UIViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] ()
    #12 0x004686c1 in _nsnote_callback ()
    #13 0x0183df99 in __CFXNotificationPost_old ()
    #14 0x017bd33a in _CFXNotificationPostNotification ()
    #15 0x0045e266 in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] ()
    #16 0x0046a5a9 in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] ()
    #17 0x00703108 in -[UIApplication _performMemoryWarning] ()
    #18 0x0181724c in __CFNotificationCenterDarwinCallBack ()
    #19 0x017a7872 in __CFMachPortPerform ()
    #20 0x01847064 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
    #21 0x017a76f7 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
    #22 0x017a4983 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
    #23 0x017a4240 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
    #24 0x017a4161 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
    #25 0x01daa268 in GSEventRunModal ()
    #26 0x01daa32d in GSEventRun ()
    #27 0x0070d42e in UIApplicationMain ()
    #28 0x0000272e in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffee7c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a `CALayer` object that has already been released. Make sure you `release` the objects properly. Also ensure that `[super dealloc];` is not called before other objects are released